# Is it possible to launch a node.js program from outside the console?

Tags: node.js, console, external, autohotkey

Specifically I'd like to launch a node program I've written from an ahk script.

Comment: How is your script failing to do what you want to do?

Comment: It's not failing to do anything because it hasn't been scripted yet.  I searched and couldn't find any information on this so I was wondering if it's possible and if so what options there are for achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `ahk` supports running external executables and capturing their output. See the [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)

So, you use that to run your node command (something like `c:\path_to_node\node.exe c:\path_to_script\script.js`)

Comment: wow it was surprisingly easy... I thought since node needed a "node" command before the filename that that would throw it off.. but I literally just wrote "node filename.js" for the command argument and it was good.